# Storing data with Shared preferences

Tags: java, android

For past 3 days I've literally spent 6-8h/day on searching, reading and executing all kinds of examples regarding Shared Preferences without any success. I've come to a dead end...been very frustrating! My issue is as follows:

**- Objective:**
I'm currently doing a very basic math game, where the player will be given a (random) equation, with two numbers multiplied with eachother. The player will then give an answer by simply pressing one of three option-buttons (one including the correct answere). Scores are added for each correct answers.

**- Problem:**
NOW, I want to include a High Score for the game to store the highest score. How do I get around to store my data using shared preferences or any other working method.

"Score:" (@+id/textScore) is my TextView that contains the score (TESTActivity.java).     "Top Scores" (@+id/textTopScores) is my TextView where I want to store my high score (HighScoreActivity.java).

**- Structure of the App:**

```
My app looks like this:
(a) MainActivity - main page with a start button leading the player to the Menu (= MenuActivity)
(b) MenuActivity - here the player have 3 buttons options which includes:
       Play Button --> leading to the TESTActivity
       High Score button -->> leading to the HighScoreActivity
       Help button -->> leading to the HelpActivity
```

.

**activity_test.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.android.laboration2.TESTActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textOperator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textPartA"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="x"
            android:textSize="55sp" />

        <TextView
            android:text="="
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textOperator"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textOperator"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textOperator"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textSize="70sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textPartA"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/buttonChoice1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonChoice1"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textPartB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textOperator"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonChoice3"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonChoice3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonChoice2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonChoice1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="4"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonChoice3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonChoice2"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="6"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonChoice1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textScore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Score:"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonChoice2"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/buttonChoice2"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textLevel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Level:"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textScore"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textScore"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textPartB"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textPartB" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**TESTActivity.java**

```js
package com.example.android.laboration2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Random;


public class TESTActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    Button buttonObjectChoice1;
    Button buttonObjectChoice2;
    Button buttonObjectChoice3;
    TextView textObjectPartA;
    TextView textObjectPartB;
    TextView textObjectScore;
    TextView textObjectLevel;
    TextView textObjectHighScoresScores;

    int correctAnswer;
    int currentScore = 0;
    int currentLevel = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);


        textObjectPartA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textPartA);
        textObjectPartB = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textPartB);
        textObjectHighScoresScores = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textHighScoresScores);

        textObjectScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textScore);
        textObjectLevel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLevel);

        buttonObjectChoice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice1);
        buttonObjectChoice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice2);
        buttonObjectChoice3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice3);

        buttonObjectChoice1.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonObjectChoice2.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonObjectChoice3.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Storing the score
        String highScore = textObjectHighScoresScores.getText().toString();
        int newHighScore = currentScore;

        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("StoringScore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt(highScore, newHighScore);
        editor.apply();


        setQuestion();
    }//onCreate ends here



    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //Declaring a new int which will be used in all the cases
        int answerGiven = 0;
        switch (view.getId()) {

            //Initializes a new int with a value for buttonObjectChoice1,2,3
            case R.id.buttonChoice1:
                answerGiven = Integer.parseInt("" + buttonObjectChoice1.getText());
                break;

            case R.id.buttonChoice2:
                answerGiven = Integer.parseInt("" + buttonObjectChoice2.getText());
                break;

            case R.id.buttonChoice3:
                answerGiven = Integer.parseInt("" + buttonObjectChoice3.getText());
                break;
        }//switch ends here

        updateScoreAndLevel(answerGiven);
        setQuestion();
        
    }//onClick ends here



    void setQuestion() {
        //Generates the parts of the question
        int numberRange = currentLevel * 3;
        Random randInt = new Random();

        int partA = randInt.nextInt(numberRange);
        partA++;//To avoid a zero value

        int partB = randInt.nextInt(numberRange);
        partB++;//To avoid a zero value

        correctAnswer = partA * partB;
        int wrongAnswer1 = correctAnswer - 2;
        int wrongAnswer2 = correctAnswer + 2;

        textObjectPartA.setText("" + partA);
        textObjectPartB.setText("" + partB);

        //Gives a number between 0 and 2 for the multi choice buttons
        int buttonLayout = randInt.nextInt(3);
        switch (buttonLayout) {
            case 0:
                buttonObjectChoice1.setText("" + correctAnswer);
                buttonObjectChoice2.setText("" + wrongAnswer1);
                buttonObjectChoice3.setText("" + wrongAnswer2);
                break;

            case 1:
                buttonObjectChoice2.setText("" + correctAnswer);
                buttonObjectChoice3.setText("" + wrongAnswer1);
                buttonObjectChoice1.setText("" + wrongAnswer2);
                break;

            case 2:
                buttonObjectChoice3.setText("" + correctAnswer);
                buttonObjectChoice1.setText("" + wrongAnswer1);
                buttonObjectChoice2.setText("" + wrongAnswer2);
                break;
                
        }//switch ends here
    }//setQuestion ends here


    //Updates the Score & Level for the player
    void updateScoreAndLevel(int answerGiven){
        if(isCorrect(answerGiven)){
            for(int i = 1; i <= currentLevel; i++){
                currentScore = currentScore + i;
            }
            currentLevel++;
        }else{
            currentScore = 0;
            currentLevel = 1;
        }
        //Updates the Score & Level TextViews
        textObjectScore.setText("Score: " + currentScore);
        textObjectLevel.setText("Level: " + currentLevel);
    }//updateScoreAndLevel ends here


    //Sends a toast message to the player - if right = Correct!, if wrong = Wrong! :(.
    boolean isCorrect(int answerGiven){
        boolean correctTrueOrFalse;
        if(answerGiven == correctAnswer){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            correctTrueOrFalse=true;
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong! :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            correctTrueOrFalse=false;
        }
        return correctTrueOrFalse;
    }//isCorrect ends here



}//TESTActivity ends here
```

**activity_high_score.xml**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_high_score"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.laboration2.HighScoreActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/high_scores"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:id="@+id/textHighScore"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/top_scores"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textTopScores"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textHighScore"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**HighScoreActivity.java**

```js
package com.example.android.laboration2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HighScoreActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_high_score);

        //getting preferences
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("StoringScore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int newHighscore = prefs.getInt(highScore, null); //0 is the default value
        
    }//onCreate ends here


}//HighScoreActivity ends here
```

Comment: Is your line textObjectHighScoresScores = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textHighScoresScores); correct? I can't find R.id.textHighScoresScores anywhere, do you mean R.id.textHighScore?

Comment: @Luke: I made a mistake there (typical!). Wanted to make things as clear as possible and changed the id and any possible name to facilitate the reading. Apparently I missed that I already had a TextView using same id (in the activity_high_score.xml). So the second TextView in the **"activity_high_score.xml"** with the string-text: **android:text="@string/top_scores"** is the one I'm refering too and that was named textHighScoresScores before and is supposed to be called **textTopScores** (and not textHighScore as it is now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//I hope this will help you
public class TESTActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

Button buttonObjectChoice1;
Button buttonObjectChoice2;
Button buttonObjectChoice3;
TextView textObjectPartA;
TextView textObjectPartB;
TextView textObjectScore;
TextView textObjectLevel;
TextView textObjectHighScoresScores;

int correctAnswer;
int currentScore = 0;
int currentLevel = 1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    textObjectPartA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textPartA);
    textObjectPartB = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textPartB);
    //textObjectHighScoresScores = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textScore);

    textObjectScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textScore);
    textObjectLevel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLevel);

    buttonObjectChoice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice1);
    buttonObjectChoice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice2);
    buttonObjectChoice3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoice3);

    buttonObjectChoice1.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonObjectChoice2.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonObjectChoice3.setOnClickListener(this);

    setQuestion();
}//onCreate ends here



@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    //Declaring a new int which will be used in all the cases
    int answerGiven = 0;
    switch (view.getId()) {

        //Initializes a new int with a value for buttonObjectChoice1,2,3
        case R.id.buttonChoice1:
            answerGiven = Integer.parseInt("" + buttonObjectChoice1.getText());
            break;

        case R.id.buttonChoice2:
            answerGiven = Integer.parseInt("" + buttonObjectChoice2.getText());
            break;

        case R.id.buttonChoice3:
            answerGiven = Integer.parseInt("" + buttonObjectChoice3.getText());
            break;
    }//switch ends here

    updateScoreAndLevel(answerGiven);
    setQuestion();

}//onClick ends here



void setQuestion() {
    //Generates the parts of the question
    int numberRange = currentLevel * 3;
    Random randInt = new Random();

    int partA = randInt.nextInt(numberRange);
    partA++;//To avoid a zero value

    int partB = randInt.nextInt(numberRange);
    partB++;//To avoid a zero value

    correctAnswer = partA * partB;
    int wrongAnswer1 = correctAnswer - 2;
    int wrongAnswer2 = correctAnswer + 2;

    textObjectPartA.setText("" + partA);
    textObjectPartB.setText("" + partB);

    //Gives a number between 0 and 2 for the multi choice buttons
    int buttonLayout = randInt.nextInt(3);
    switch (buttonLayout) {
        case 0:
            buttonObjectChoice1.setText("" + correctAnswer);
            buttonObjectChoice2.setText("" + wrongAnswer1);
            buttonObjectChoice3.setText("" + wrongAnswer2);
            break;

        case 1:
            buttonObjectChoice2.setText("" + correctAnswer);
            buttonObjectChoice3.setText("" + wrongAnswer1);
            buttonObjectChoice1.setText("" + wrongAnswer2);
            break;

        case 2:
            buttonObjectChoice3.setText("" + correctAnswer);
            buttonObjectChoice1.setText("" + wrongAnswer1);
            buttonObjectChoice2.setText("" + wrongAnswer2);
            break;

    }//switch ends here
}//setQuestion ends here


//Updates the Score & Level for the player
void updateScoreAndLevel(int answerGiven){
    if(isCorrect(answerGiven)){
        for(int i = 1; i <= currentLevel; i++){
            currentScore = currentScore + i;
        }
        currentLevel++;
    }else{
        currentScore = 0;
        currentLevel = 1;
    }
    //Updates the Score & Level TextViews
    textObjectScore.setText("Score: " + currentScore);
    textObjectLevel.setText("Level: " + currentLevel);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    int storedHighScore = sharedPreferences.getInt("highScore",0);
    if (currentScore>storedHighScore){
        editor.putInt("highScore",currentScore);
        editor.commit();
    }
}//updateScoreAndLevel ends here


//Sends a toast message to the player - if right = Correct!, if wrong = Wrong! :(.
boolean isCorrect(int answerGiven){
    boolean correctTrueOrFalse;
    if(answerGiven == correctAnswer){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        correctTrueOrFalse=true;
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong! :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        correctTrueOrFalse=false;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,HighScoreActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return correctTrueOrFalse;
}//isCorrect ends here



}//TESTActivity ends here
```

//HighScoreActivity

```
public class HighScoreActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView highScoreTextView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_high_score);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences",MODE_PRIVATE);
    int storedHighScore = sharedPreferences.getInt("highScore",0);

    highScoreTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textHighScore);
    highScoreTextView.setText(""+storedHighScore);


    }
}
```

Comment: Shehxhad: Doesn't work. Each time I go to the TESTActivity to play the app it crashes each time :/.

Comment: Would you like to share screenshot of Android Monitor when app crashes

Comment: I swapped the above: textObjectHighScoresScores = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textHighScoresScores); with **textObjectScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textScore);** now the app doesn't crash. Maybe you missunderstood before. The **R.id.textScore** is where my actual score are added. The **R.id.textObejctHighScoresScore** is where I want the High Score to be stored & showed.

Comment: In your test_activity.xml there is no textview with this id textHighScoresScores

Comment: I apologize for that Sid. I'm a fool and screwed up. If you look above you'll see I made a comment about it. I tried to edit my post, but apparently it's not possible -.-'.

Comment: **textObjectScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textScore);** = where my score is added. In the above post **textObjectHighScoresScores = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textHighScoresScores);** is the TextView where I want to display the High Score.

Comment: Okay no problem. Did you get correct solution? if not I can make this code perfect for you

Comment: The app works. But I don't know how to display the High Score and it's not as well fully functional. The part where I retrieve the values (using your code posted above), the **highScore** is shown in grey (= never used). If you don't mind i would appreciate that. If you need any further clarification let me know.

Comment: is the TESTActivity.java correctly updated? I can't see any of the codes related to the Shared preferences or any other extra codes added?

Comment: The code that I just have sent you is perfectly working for me. Just check the sharedpreferences line before isCorrect Function.

Comment: @FisnikB. ... did you read my answer or not? your are making mistake with key

Comment: Yeah I did Abhishek, I even copied same code and didn't get it to work :/. I need to be able after storing to retrieve the data & display it as well.

Comment: @SidShehxad it doesn't work. When I press play it stopps working.

Comment: Why is stop working? Did you check your Android Device Monitor? There must be something that you are not showing us. You need to show screenshot of your android monitor when it stops

Comment: Sid - Thank you so much! It works perfectly good! Can't thank you enough! Once again, my apology for confusing things up and for not paying attention, like you said your code above works like a charm. I just didn't notice that you had moved the "Shared Preferences" to where the actual score were being updated!

Answer (score 4):

**Actually main problem is here.**

```
 //Storing the score
    String highScore = textObjectHighScoresScores.getText().toString();
    int newHighScore = currentScore;

    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("StoringScore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt(highScore, newHighScore);
    editor.apply();
```

`editor.putInt(key,value)` you are using high score as key which will be change, but shared preference can be get by same key which is used a time of storing.

**You should store like this**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("StoringScore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("myKey", score);
editor.apply();
```

**Get score by->**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("StoringScore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int newHighscore = prefs.getInt("myKey", 0);
```

> Main point is **KEY** should be same

Comment: Sorry for not replying Abhishek. As posted below, I copy/pasted same codes as you wrote above without success. Any tip what I'm doing wrong? Because I've seen your post before in other topics and tried it before as well. Just like then I didn't get it to work (probably because I'm new and confused).

Comment: @FisnikB. if your are new then create a simple program for testing the shared preference then implement into you current program.. my point is. your problem is this line .... `editor.putInt(highScore,newHightScore)`. instead of that all you need to do is `editor,putInt("high_score",newhighscore)` and for getting result  `pref.getInt("high_score",0)`. first parameter is key which is use to get spacific value. key should be same at time of storing and getting value.. just use same string that i have used

Comment: Thank you for all help Abishek. It is now solved using the full code that Sid Shehxad sent me below. That was much easier for me as now I can see as well how it should have been executed (which I think my main problem was before).